# How to set boundaries for an actor?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm making an actor (*sprite*) go from left of the screen to right and then back to left (*loop animation*). After a few seconds the actor starts moving way too left/right off the screen. I'm using ***setLinearVelocity*** method to move the actor. This is the code inside a Timer:

```
if (actor.getX() < (LEFT_EDGE + actor.getWidth())) {
    // if at the edge of left, go right
    actor.body.setLinearVelocity(ACTOR_MOVE_SPEED, actor.body.getLinearVelocity().y);
    actor.setScaleX(Math.abs(actor.getScaleX()));
}

else if (actor.getX() > (RIGHT_EDGE - actor.getWidth())) {
    // if at the edge of right, go left
    actor.body.setLinearVelocity(-ACTOR_MOVE_SPEED, actor.body.getLinearVelocity().y);
    actor.setScaleX(Math.abs(actor.getScaleX()));
}
```

How do I set the boundary for the actor so that it doesn't leave the screen/go off the screen? And why does it go off the screen anyways?

P.S. The actor body is kinematic.

Comment: @CaseyB Isn't LibGDX a framework of Java?

Comment: It's a C library that has Java bindings. I removed the Java tag because your question is about how libGDX works, not about how Java works.

Comment: Just about every Libgdx question on this site has the Java tag. It's convenient for automatic code formatting, and presumably the OP wants the answer in Java. Libgdx is not a C library.